# How to make a RecyclerView with a ratngBar inside it so the the user can rate the RecylerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ratingbar

How to handle user feedback via ratingbars embedded in RecyclerView?

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

### food_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:text="Food Name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

### FoodItem.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewproject2;

public class FoodItem {
    private int foodImage;
    private String foodName;
    private int foodRating;

    public FoodItem(int foodImage, String foodName, int foodRating) {
        this.foodImage = foodImage;
        this.foodName = foodName;
        this.foodRating = foodRating;
    }

    public int getFoodImage() {
        return foodImage;
    }

    public void setFoodImage(int foodImage) {
        this.foodImage = foodImage;
    }

    public String getFoodName() {
        return foodName;
    }

    public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
        this.foodName = foodName;
    }

    public int getFoodRating() {
        return foodRating;
    }

    public void setFoodRating(int foodRating) {
        this.foodRating = foodRating;
    }
}
```

---

This is

### FoodAdapter.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewproject2;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<FoodItem> arrayList;

    public static class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView viewHolderImageView;
        private TextView  viewHolderTextView;
        private RatingBar viewHolderRatigBar;

        public FoodViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            viewHolderImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            viewHolderTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            viewHolderRatigBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        }
    }

    public FoodAdapter(ArrayList<FoodItem> foodList) {
        arrayList = foodList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.food_item, viewGroup, false);
        FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder = new FoodViewHolder(view);
        return foodViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder, int i) {
        FoodItem currentItem = arrayList.get(i);
        foodViewHolder.viewHolderImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getFoodImage());
        foodViewHolder.viewHolderTextView.setText(currentItem.getFoodName());
        foodViewHolder.viewHolderRatigBar.setRating(currentItem.getFoodRating());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

---

And this is

### ActivityMain.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewproject2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<FoodItem> foodList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Adapter adapter;
    private LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createFoodList();
        buildRecyclerView();
    }

    private void createFoodList() {
        foodList = new ArrayList<>();
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.a, "a", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.b, "b", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.c, "c", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.d, "d", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.e, "e", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.f, "f", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.g, "g", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.h, "h", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.i, "i", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.j, "j", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.k, "k", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.l, "n", 0));
        foodList.add(new FoodItem(R.drawable.m, "m", 0));
    }

    private void buildRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapter = new FoodAdapter(foodList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have been working on.

Comment: What specifically is not working? What is the undesirable behavior you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use add the `OnRatingBarChangeListener` to handle the `OnRatingBarChanged` event.

Add the necesary code to the `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder, int i) {
    FoodItem currentItem = arrayList.get(i);
    foodViewHolder.viewHolderImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getFoodImage());
    foodViewHolder.viewHolderTextView.setText(currentItem.getFoodName());

    foodViewHolder.viewHolderRatigBar.setRating(currentItem.getFoodRating());       
    foodViewHolder.viewHolderRatigBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onRatingBarChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser){
            currentItem.setFoodRating(rating);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:
The value "rating" passed to the `onRatingBarChanged()` method is of type `float` so you will need to change your `FoodItem` class to accommodate this type.

If you wish to persist this value you will need to include some mechanism to save the new rating value--perhaps in a database.